# I want to lengthen the double vertical line

Tags: math-mode

I need to use the symbol `||\frac{1}{2} W||_F`.  I know if lengthen a vertical line, i can use the command `\big|`. But how to lengthen the double vertical line `||`?

Comment: Normally you should not use `||` for that.

Comment: Remember the `\| \|`.